# How to get return URL from WebView after successful payment in Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have integrated a payment gateway in my Xamarin Forms app. After filling the payment details I am opening the payment page in WebView to complete the payment. When the payment is completed it returns a URL with the payment status code. Now the question is that how can I get this return URL in my Xamarin Forms app?

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer? @Prãshant Saraswat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of all, I strongly recommend you to take a look if that payment system which you are using has some kind of support via SDK or API which you can use to complete that paying process, without using WebView.*

On the other hand, if you are already decided to use WebView for that, you can use `Navigating` event from `Xamarin.Forms` `WebView`.

`Navigating` is an event that is raised when navigation starts.

Use it in C#:

```
yourWebView.Navigating += YourWebView_Navigating;
```

Or in XAML:

```
<WebView Navigating="YourWebView_Navigating" 
...
```

and in your code-behind you have the access to `WebNavigatingEventArgs` it:

```
void YourWebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url // check the value of it
    // other code logic.
```

Using it you will get access to `WebNavigatingEventArgs` which holds a property called `Url`, with that info you can check the URL value and combine that with other logic in your app, navigate the user away or whatever you intended to do after successful payment.

Hope this was helpful for you, wishing you lots of luck with coding!

Comment: If you are using MVVM you can also use EventToCommand behaviour to convert this event to your Command in VM, but that is another topic. Good luck!

Comment: :) Thanks Almir Vuk, you saved my day. It worked! Cheers!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you also tell me if my app will be approved on Google Play or App Store as I am using WebView to accept payments online?

Comment: Was your app approved on Google Play and App Store using webview paypal method?